# how to change auth username after user profile edit in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a situation where i need to allow current logged in user to change his username in cakephp. 
when i update the username in database it doesn't reflect in

```
 $this->Auth->user('username')
```

Even after changing record in database $this->Auth->user('username') is giving same old username because it is saved in current session.

can anyone help me in how to update current $this->Auth session data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The AuthComponent stores the User's properties inside the session on login. Updating the User-data inside the database won't automatically update those changes inside the session, so you'll have to do that yourself after successfully saving the changes to the database;

### Manually log in after update

Although the user already is logged in, manually logging the User in, will also update the data inside the Session (see the source here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L543)

Something like this;

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    // Succesfully update the user
    // update the users data inside the session
    $this->Auth->login($this->request->data);

    // and redirect somewhere else
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
}
```

Although you'll be able to achieve the same by updating the session-data via the Session-component, doing this via the AuthComponent is easier, as it will automatically store the data in the right location inside the session :)

Also see: [Identifying users and logging them in](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in)

**note** Because you didn't mention what version of CakePHP you're using, I'm assuming CakePHP 2.x

Comment: Correct solution @theJeztah.. great

Comment: @liyakat thanks! I thought this would be a cleaner solution than manually updating the session, as that would involve getting the right 'key' inside the session via `AuthComponent::$sessionKey`

Comment: the problem with this approach could be, as [documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-AuthComponent.html#_login), or your link to source says, that if you pass an argument to the login function, "that data will be stored as the logged in user" - which means only values in the request will be stored in session and not complete user information as cake gets it normally from database during login

Answer (score 3):

After updating the new name in database, you can just update the name in session as below:

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.User.name', $new_username);
```

This line of code will update the username within the same session.

Answer (score 0):

you have just to change the session data for the username

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.User.username') = $newusername;
```

for example

```
 $this->Session->write('Auth.User.username') = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
```